# Allow shortcode in the author bio textarea

Tags: shortcode, author

Is it possible to make shortcodes available in the Author bio textarea?

Comment: Wouldn't that be a matter of `do_shortcode` when printing its value on the front-end?

Comment: @brasofilo Should be an answer :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It a matter of using [**`do_shortcode`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) in your `author.php` template file (or wherever applies). This function has to be "`echo`ed". And instead of using `the_author_meta` (which `echo`'s the result), use `get_the_author_meta`.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) ); ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

in functions.php

```
add_filter( 'get_the_author_description', 'do_shortcode');
```